# Show & hide a div using a radio select

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, show-hide

I am trying to show a section of my code depending on what the user selects via a radio button. Essentially, I want the elevator_choice to show up only if the users selects 'Second' in the first set of buttons.

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="floor" value="First">First
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="floor" value="Second">Second
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding: 0 0 10px 0; display:none;" id="elevator_choice">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="elevator" value="No">No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[name$='floor']").click(function() {
       if($(this).val() == 'First') {
            $('#elevator_choice').hide();           
       }
       else {
            $('#elevator_choice').show();   
       }
   });
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meB7p/)

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mr9ah/

Comment: Your code works fine.. only show "No" if "Second" is selected, check this link http://jsfiddle.net/38zea/ ... maybe the jquery.js is not included.

Comment: mmm, weird... when I check on the console the function seems to run when the page loads instead of when I click. And then when I do click on the button it does not get called. Could that be it?

Comment: or may be you should share the fiddle.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/meB7p/

Comment: @LuisP In your fiddle, forgot select the jquery version in the Frameworks & Extensions section, select jquery 1.9 (for example) and test again.

Comment: @SoldierCorp, ok, that seems to have made it work... must be my jquery lib not getting added correctly as you suggested.  I am adding as '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @LuisP http://jsfiddle.net/meB7p/1/

Comment: Sure, I didn't nothing :P

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/meB7p/2/ I hope you get an idea...

Answer (score 0):

```
Add class name to each radio input and register click event on this input, before showing check whether the text is first or not.


<div class="row" style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input class="check" type="radio" name="floor" value="First">First
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input class="check" type="radio" name="floor" value="Second">Second
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding: 0 0 10px 0; display:none;" id="elevator_choice">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="elevator" value="No">No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.check').click(function() {
       if($(this).val() == 'Second') {
            $('#elevator_choice').show();           
       }
       else {
            $('#elevator_choice').hide();   
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the problem.  I am using Twitter Bootstrap and for some reason Bootstrap adds some style to the buttons so that the 'onclick' event does not work.  I changed it to 'onchange' and it works now.

Thanks everyone